# validation of selecting time of a date that had already been selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I had dynamic number of drop downs of two type on for date another for time.They are use for booking classes.Now if a user select a particular time of a particular time,then he will not set same time for same date for next class.How to do it in jquery or javascript?

Comment: Have you proceed up to some extends,The logic is that when a user select a date time for a class then store that value in a hidden field or a javascript variable(array).Now when the user again trying to select another first check the value does not matches with any value in the javascript array if it is anew one thenninsert the value in the array, and with a ajax call save it in a database. And on page reload populate the javascript array from the backend.

Comment: We really need to see some code to help with this one ...

Comment: All i need to do is that if a user select 25-12-14 as date and 12.00Am as time for class1,then i would like to show an alert if he select same time and same date for class2 and so on